# How to display an image saved on database in .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to display an image saved to the database, I've been looking for tutorials and more, but they haven't really been of much help. I have an API controller and it is used by an MVC view and its respective controller. In the view there is a space to display text and the space where the image should be, the image is saved in the database as type `varbinary` and the text is a field of type `varchar`.

The model I have created:

```
public class ForumContentModel
{
    //some other fields
    //theme tables
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public byte[] ContentFile { get; set; } //this has the image
    public string FileType { get; set; }//the ext type of the image
    public string FileName { get; set; }//the name of the img

}
```

The API controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("watchPost/{IdPost}")]
    public IActionResult verPost(int IdPost)
    {
        ForumContentModel forum = new ForumContentModel();//this model is used to "join" various
                                                          //models

        //get the data from the different tables with the id sending from the MVC controller
        var forumContent = db.Themes.Where(x => x.IdForo == IdPost).FirstOrDefault();            

        //Content data from the post

        forum.Content = forumContent.Content;//the text part

        forum.ContentFile = forumContent.ContentFile;//the image
        return Ok(forum);
     }
```

The MVC controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult watchPost(int Id)
    {
        ForumContentModel forumModel = new ForumContentModel();

        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44325/api/Forum/");

            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("watchPost/" + Id);

            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;

            if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<ForumContentModel>();
                readTask.Wait();

                forumModel = readTask.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error");
            }
        }

        return View(forumModel);
    }
```

The view where the data is displayed:

```
       <form asp-action="watchPost">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-8">
                    <!--Text content-->
                    <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label h2"></label>
                    <textarea rows="4" asp-for="Content" class="form-control border-0" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-4">

                    <!--where the image should be desplayed-->
                    <img asp-for="<!--the route or the @Http.DisplayFor to bring the image?-->" alt="" class="img-fluid">

                </div>
            </div>        
        </form>
```

I really don't know how to do this, I've been looking in some tutorials and almost all of them put in the source of the img attribute the name of the folder where the image is stored.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Just use a HttpHandler as the source of your image, which pull the image from the database and returns it.

Comment: @DaleK, thanks for the comment, I was doing that, but the `@HttpHandler` is not showing up and it throws an error.

Comment: Then add that code to your question along with the error.

Comment: Well, you suggested to use `@HttpHandler` as the source of the image, I did the following:`<img src = "@HttpHandler ..." alt = "" class = "img-fluid">`, but in the `@HttpHandler` shows that it does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to the following sample code:

Model: In my sample, I stored the file in database via the AppFile, you could change it to yours.

[Note] In your sample, the model's name is `ContentForoModel`, but in the controller, the model's name is `ForumContentModel`, please check your code and use the correct model.

```
public class AppFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
public class ContentForoModel
{
    //some other fields
    //theme tables
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public byte[] ContentFile { get; set; } //this has the image
    public string FileType { get; set; }//the ext type of the image
    public string FileName { get; set; }//the name of the img

}
```

API controller: query the database based on the ID, and return the specified model.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public TodoController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("watchPost/{IdPost}")]
    public IActionResult watchPost(int IdPost)
    {
        ContentForoModel forum = new ContentForoModel();//this model is used to "join" various
                                                          //models

        //get the data from the different tables with the id sending from the MVC controller
        var appfile = _context.AppFiles.Where(x => x.Id == IdPost).FirstOrDefault();

        //Content data from the post

        forum.Content = appfile.Name;//the text part

        forum.ContentFile = appfile.Content;//the image
        return Ok(forum);
    }
```

MVC Controller: You could change the url to yours.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> watchPost(int Id)
    {
        ContentForoModel forumModel = new ContentForoModel();
        if (Id == 0)
            Id = 1;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44310/api/todo/");

            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("watchPost/" + Id);

            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var apiResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //required using Newtonsoft.Json;
                forumModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentForoModel>(apiResponse);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error");
            }
        }

        return View(forumModel);
    }
```

View page: First, convert the byte array to base64 string, then, set the image src attribute.

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.ContentForoModel
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="watchPost">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-8">
                    <!--Text content-->
                    <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label h2"></label>
                    <textarea rows="4" asp-for="Content" class="form-control border-0" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                    <label asp-for="ContentFile" class="control-label h2"></label>
                    @{
                        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ContentFile);
                        var Image = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
                    }
                    <img src="@Image" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a second `ApiController` for serving images.

Create a method returning an `HttpResponseMessage` and taking some kind of ID for the image as a parameter.

Inside that method construct a response and set the Content to a stream.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(...);
```

Set the MIME type for the message, probably ONE of these:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/svg+xml");
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
```

Optionally set some headers to help caching:

```
response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
{
    Public = true,
    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
};
```

Your view will need to generate an `img` tag pointing to this second controller/method.

Comment: Don't forget to set the mime type :P.

Comment: @Aron, thanks, missed that in my copy-paste from working code.