# Net 5 System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer returns incomplete json

Tags: json, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webapi controller and a method like below to retrieve records in the SQL Server database through Entity Framework. The tblQuestion has several foreign keys to the tblCodeSet which has a self referencing CodeSetParent property. The webapi works in the Swagger UI and Postman. However, when it is called with the HttpClient in the APIAgent, the DeserializeAsync<>() failed with error

```js
"Expected depth to be zero at the end of the JSON payload. There is an open JSON object or array that should be closed. Path: $.$values"
```

The downloaded json from Postman has 2013 lines but only one record is serialized with very deep navagation references.  Even worse is the json array is not closed.  I wonder if it is because the tblQuestion have deep navigations that exceeds json payload. Thanks for your help.

```js
namespace IPRehabModel
{
   public partial class TblCodeSet
   {
      public TblCodeSet()
      {
         InverseCodeSetParentNavigation = new HashSet<TblCodeSet>();
         TblAnswer = new HashSet<TblAnswer>();
         TblQuestionStage = new HashSet<TblQuestionStage>();
         TblQuestionAnswerCodeSetFkNavigation = new HashSet<TblQuestion>();
         TblQuestionFormFkNavigation = new HashSet<TblQuestion>();
         TblQuestionFormSectionFkNavigation = new HashSet<TblQuestion>();
      }

      public int CodeSetId { get; set; }
      public int? CodeSetParent { get; set; }
      public string CodeValue { get; set; }
      public string CodeDescription { get; set; }
      public int? HierarchyType { get; set; }
      public bool? Active { get; set; }
      public int? FyConstraint { get; set; }
      public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
      public string Comment { get; set; }

      public virtual TblCodeSet CodeSetParentNavigation { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<TblCodeSet> InverseCodeSetParentNavigation { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<TblAnswer> TblAnswer { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<TblQuestionStage> TblQuestionStage { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<TblQuestion> TblQuestionAnswerCodeSetFkNavigation { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<TblQuestion> TblQuestionFormFkNavigation { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<TblQuestion> TblQuestionFormSectionFkNavigation { get; set; }
   }
}
```

```js
namespace IPRehabModel {
  public partial class TblQuestion {
    public TblQuestion() {
      TblAnswer = new HashSet < TblAnswer > ();
      TblQuestionInstruction = new HashSet < TblQuestionInstruction > ();
    }

    public int QuestionId {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string QuestionKey {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public int ? Order {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string QuestionTitle {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string Question {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string GroupTitle {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public int FormFk {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public int ? FormSectionFk {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public int AnswerCodeSetFk {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public bool ? BranchingPoint {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public bool ? MultiChoice {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public virtual TblCodeSet AnswerCodeSetFkNavigation {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public virtual TblCodeSet FormFkNavigation {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public virtual TblCodeSet FormSectionFkNavigation {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public virtual ICollection < TblAnswer > TblAnswer {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public virtual ICollection < TblQuestionInstruction > TblQuestionInstruction {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public virtual ICollection < TblQuestionStage > TblQuestionStage {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
namespace IPRehabWebAPI2.Controllers {
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class QuestionsController: ControllerBase {
    private readonly IQuestionRepository _questionRepository;

    public QuestionsController(IQuestionRepository questionRepository) {
      _questionRepository = questionRepository;
    }
    public ActionResult < IEnumerable < TblQuestion >> GetInitStage() {
      var questions = _questionRepository.FindByCondition(x => x.TblQuestionStage
        .Where(s => s.QuestionIdFk == x.QuestionId &&
          s.StageFkNavigation.CodeValue == "Initial").Any());

      return Ok(questions);
    }

  }
}
```

```js
namespace IPRehab.Helpers {
  public static class APIAgent {
    public static async Task < IEnumerable < TblQuestion >> StreamWithSystemTextJson(Uri uri, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
      using
      var client = new HttpClient();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
      //Define request data format  
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      using
      var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

      httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 

      if (httpResponse.Content is object && httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json") {
        var contentStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        try {
          return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync < IEnumerable < TblQuestion >> (contentStream, options);
        } catch (JsonException ex) // Invalid JSON
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response was invalid and cannot be deserialised.");
      }

      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to configure [circular reference handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0). It has nothing to do with EF Core, just make sure to turn lazy loading off (in case you are using it) because all these `virtual` properties will automatically include in the response a lot of data that you might not need.

Comment: Yes, I have set that in the startup.cs ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services).


         services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(o =>
         {
            //preserve circular reference
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
         });

Comment: When read the returned data from the response, try to replace the `ReadAsStreamAsync()` method, and use the `ReadAsStringAsync()` method. Then, you could get the JSON string. After that, you could set a break point to check whether the JSON string is complete or not and use the JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync() method to convert the JSON string to Object.

Comment: @Zhi Lv:  The ReadAsStringAsync() require an IOStream object.  Could you show me how?

Comment: HI @user266909, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duifu.png), more details sample code, refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172092/how-to-display-an-image-saved-on-database-in-net-core-api/67175495#67175495).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read that there are problems with EF stopping serialization when encounters a null property along the paths.  Instead of letting EF deep navigate, I created a DTO and hydrate it with the .Select() to project domain properties.

```js
var questions = _questionRepository.FindByCondition(x => x.Active.Value != false && x.TblQuestionStage
    .Where(s => s.QuestionIdFk == x.QuestionId &&
      s.StageFkNavigation.CodeValue == "Initial").Any())
  .Select(q => HydrateDTO.Hydrate(q))
  .ToList().OrderBy(o => o.DisplayOrder).ThenBy(o => o.QuestionKey);
```

```js
using IPRehabModel;
using IPRehabWebAPI2.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace IPRehabWebAPI2.Helpers {

  /// <summary>
  /// Hydrate the DTO with selected domain properties
  /// </summary>
  public class HydrateDTO {
    //ToDo: should use AutoMapper
    public static QuestionDTO Hydrate(TblQuestion q) {
      return new QuestionDTO {
        QuestionID = q.QuestionId,
          QuestionKey = q.QuestionKey,
          QuestionTitle = q.QuestionTitle,
          Question = q.Question,
          GroupTitle = q.GroupTitle,
          AnswerCodeSetID = q.AnswerCodeSetFk,
          DisplayOrder = q.Order,
          ChoiceList = q.AnswerCodeSetFkNavigation.InverseCodeSetParentNavigation
          .Select(s => new CodeSetDTO {
            CodeSetID = s.CodeSetId,
              CodeSetParent = s.CodeSetParent,
              CodeValue = s.CodeValue,
              CodeDescription = s.CodeDescription,
              Comment = s.Comment
          }).ToList()
      };
    }
  }
}
```